# How to change font size of eclipse XML context-sensitive-doc

Tags: eclipse

The default font size of eclipse context sensitive help FOR XML is too small to see.
I tried General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts, but it does not work.
My OS is windows7, eclipse version is Indigo Service Release 1.

The screen shot of context sensitive help is below.
[image: eclipse context sensitive help]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Preferences / General / Appearance / Colors and Fonts - Java / Javadoc display font

Comment: thanks greg, I tried this method, it does work for Java editor, but not for my case which is an editor of xml such as spring configure files. It has no effects for xml context-sensitive popup help. Thanks for your answer, I has changed the question to be more specifically on XML context sensitive help.